# In Firebase I am getting an Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'initializeApp' of undefined, but not sure why 'firebase' is not defined?

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, typeerror

here's my firebase import etc. in the config file, why would this be unable to recognise firebase?

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app'
import 'firebase/firestore'
import 'firebase/auth'

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "XXX",
  authDomain: "XXX",
  projectId: "XXX",
  storageBucket: "XXX",
  messagingSenderId: "XXX",
  appId: "XXX",
  measurementId: "XXX"
}

//init firebase
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)

const projectAuth = firebase.auth()
const projectFirestore = firebase.firestore()
const timestamp = firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp

export { projectAuth, projectFirestore, timestamp }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have installed version `9.0.0` then  you would have to use compat libraries to use the namespaced version:

```
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app'
import 'firebase/compat/firestore'
import 'firebase/compat/auth'
```

Although I'd recommend using the new Modular syntax which is designed to facilitate tree-shaking (removal of unused code) to make your web app as small and fast as possible.

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app"
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore"

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig)

const projectAuth = getAuth(app)
const projectFirestore = getFirestore(app)

export { projectAuth, projectFirestore }
```

You can find detailed information in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade)